# Batch Screenshots of 500 Video Files Into One Folder

Tags: batch-file, video, screenshot

I have about 500 AVI files of home videos in a single folder. I want to take screenshots of each video at a rate of, say, every 5 seconds. Preferably, each of the video's screenshots would output into one folder, with the files named after the video file they come from and then a number (such as Video File #1 1.jpg, Video File #1 2.jpg, Video File #1 3.jpg, Video File #2 1.jpg, etc). About six years ago I used a program that could do this with a single batch file, but I have long since forgotten what it was called, and can't really find anything similar. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use ffmpeg. It will do this for you in a jiffy.  See eg. http://debuggable.com/posts/FFMPEG_multiple_thumbnails:4aded79c-6744-4bc1-b30e-59bccbdd56cb

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply! That program looks extremely useful, but is there a way to have the batchfile do it for each video in a folder automatically? Or do I have to run it once per video file?

Comment: Why don't you simply put a script which will create a list of all files in the folder [ls *.avi *.mp4] etc. If you can have other types of files also in the folder and do not have control over the extension you can run either the file command or ffprobe command to check if the file is a video file. Then you need to run the command for each file.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageGrab](http://paul.glagla.free.fr/index_en.htm) will automate movie file screenshots at user-set intervals. No coding skills needed.